# Justify wrapped text in html

Tags: html, text, formatting, alignment

I am trying to do a left justify on a field by using:

```
 <TD ALIGN="left" WIDTH="20%" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;#PrimaryKeyValues#</TD>    </div>
```

But, when the text is too large, it gets wrapped around, and the wrapped text doesn't begin at the same position.

```
    PRODUCT_ID:1(Indirect Auto Retail),PREVIOUSLY_LOGGED_FLG:1,
EVALUATOR_ID:65(Product Test),DECISION_ID:1(APPCOND)
    PRODUCT_ID:1(Indirect Auto Retail),PREVIOUSLY_LOGGED_FLG:1,
EVALUATOR_ID:65(Product Test),DECISION_ID:1(APPCOND)
    USER_ID:PTKIM  
    USER_ID:PTKIM
```

Hope the above text sample shows what is happening

Comment: For future reference on html problems, please try and recreate the problem with minimal code at http://cssdesk.com or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `td` content is left-aligned by default. It seems that you are trying to *prevent* that by adding spacing. Please clarify what you want, and illustrate it with a real example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never, ever, "justify" text using (non breaking or other) spaces. Just use CSS properties for [text-align](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align), [text-wrap](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-wrap) etc. For more information check out [CSS Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/).

Comment: Agreed. This will just end in tears!

Comment: Also, the spec says that html elements are supposed to be in lower case.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs It is **convention** (or recommended) to write them in lower case. AFAIK HTML is case-insensitive ([as opposed to XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html#h-4.2)):
http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author
"In XHTML, tag names are case sensitive and are usually defined to be written in lowercase. In HTML, however, tag names are case insensitive and may be written in all uppercase or mixed case, although the most common convention is to stick with lowercase. The case of the start and end tags do not have to be the same, but being consistent does make the code look cleaner."

Comment: you are right, the non breaking spaces are evil. Removing them aligned it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use CSS for this? All those non-breaking spaces are scary looking!

```
<TD ALIGN="left" WIDTH="20%" style="text-align: justify">#PrimaryKeyValues#</TD>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Or, if you just want it indenting:

```
<TD ALIGN="left" WIDTH="20%" style="text-indent: 20px">#PrimaryKeyValues#</TD>
```

Does that help?

Thanks,
Michael.